# Find unique URLs in a file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, unique

**Situation**

I have many URLs in a file, and I need to find out how many unique URLs exist.

I would like to run either a bash script or a command.

`myfile.log`

```
/home/myfiles/www/wp-content/als/xm-sf0ab5df9c1262f2130a9b313192deca4-f0ab5df9c1262f2130a9b313192deca4-c23c5fbca96e8d641d148bac41017635|https://public.rgfl.org/HS/PowerPoint%20Presentations/Health%20and%20Safety%20Law.ppt,18,17
/home/myfiles/www/wp-content/als/xm-s4bf050d47df5bfaf0486a50a8528cb16-4bf050d47df5bfaf0486a50a8528cb16-c23c5fbca96e8d641d148bac41017635|https://public.rgfl.org/HS/PowerPoint%20Presentations/Health%20and%20Safety%20Law.ppt,15,14
/home/myfiles/www/wp-content/als/xm-sad122bf22152ba4823a520cc2fe59f40-ad122bf22152ba4823a520cc2fe59f40-c23c5fbca96e8d641d148bac41017635|https://public.rgfl.org/HS/PowerPoint%20Presentations/Health%20and%20Safety%20Law.ppt,17,16
/home/myfiles/www/wp-content/als/xm-s3c0f031eebceb0fd5c4334ecef15292d-3c0f031eebceb0fd5c4334ecef15292d-c23c5fbca96e8d641d148bac41017635|https://public.rgfl.org/HS/PowerPoint%20Presentations/Health%20and%20Safety%20Law.ppt,12,11
/home/myfiles/www/wp-content/als/xm-sff661e8c3b4f94957926d5434d0ad549-ff661e8c3b4f94957926d5434d0ad549-c23c5fbca96e8d641d148bac41017635|https://quality.gha.org/Portals/2/documents/HEN/Meetings/nursesinstitute/062013/nursesroleineliminatingharm_moddydunning.pptx,17,16
/home/myfiles/www/wp-content/als/xm-s32c41ec2a5440ad220008b9abfe9add2-32c41ec2a5440ad220008b9abfe9add2-c23c5fbca96e8d641d148bac41017635|https://quality.gha.org/Portals/2/documents/HEN/Meetings/nursesinstitute/062013/nursesroleineliminatingharm_moddydunning.pptx,19,18
/home/myfiles/www/wp-content/als/xm-s28787ca2f4372ddb3616d3fd53c161ab-28787ca2f4372ddb3616d3fd53c161ab-c23c5fbca96e8d641d148bac41017635|https://quality.gha.org/Portals/2/documents/HEN/Meetings/nursesinstitute/062013/nursesroleineliminatingharm_moddydunning.pptx,22,21
/home/myfiles/www/wp-content/als/xm-s89a7b68158e38391da9f0de1e636c0d5-89a7b68158e38391da9f0de1e636c0d5-c23c5fbca96e8d641d148bac41017635|https://quality.gha.org/Portals/2/documents/HEN/Meetings/nursesinstitute/062013/nursesroleineliminatingharm_moddydunning.pptx,13,12
/home/myfiles/www/wp-content/als/xm-sc4b14e10f6151995f21334061ff1d139-c4b14e10f6151995f21334061ff1d139-c23c5fbca96e8d641d148bac41017635|https://royalmechanical.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/hy-wire-car-2.pptx,13,12
/home/myfiles/www/wp-content/als/xm-se589d47d163e43fa0c0d68e824e2c286-e589d47d163e43fa0c0d68e824e2c286-c23c5fbca96e8d641d148bac41017635|https://royalmechanical.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/hy-wire-car-2.pptx,19,18
/home/myfiles/www/wp-content/als/xm-s52f897a623c539d09bfb988bfb153888-52f897a623c539d09bfb988bfb153888-c23c5fbca96e8d641d148bac41017635|https://royalmechanical.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/hy-wire-car-2.pptx,14,13
/home/myfiles/www/wp-content/als/xm-sccf27a904c5b88e96a3522b2e1180fed-ccf27a904c5b88e96a3522b2e1180fed-c23c5fbca96e8d641d148bac41017635|https://royalmechanical.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/hy-wire-car-2.pptx,18,17
/home/myfiles/www/wp-content/als/xm-s6874bf9d589708764dab754e5af06ddf-6874bf9d589708764dab754e5af06ddf-c23c5fbca96e8d641d148bac41017635|https://royalmechanical.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/hy-wire-car-2.pptx,17,16
/home/myfiles/www/wp-content/als/xm-s46c55ec8387dbdedd7a83b3ad541cdc1-46c55ec8387dbdedd7a83b3ad541cdc1-c23c5fbca96e8d641d148bac41017635|https://royalmechanical.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/hy-wire-car-2.pptx,19,18
/home/myfiles/www/wp-content/als/xm-s08cfdc15f5935b947bbaa93c7193d496-08cfdc15f5935b947bbaa93c7193d496-c23c5fbca96e8d641d148bac41017635|https://royalmechanical.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/hydro-power-plant.ppt,9,8
/home/myfiles/www/wp-content/als/xm-s86e267bd359c12de262c0279cee0c941-86e267bd359c12de262c0279cee0c941-c23c5fbca96e8d641d148bac41017635|https://royalmechanical.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/hydro-power-plant.ppt,15,14
/home/myfiles/www/wp-content/als/xm-s5aa60354d134b87842918d760ec8bc30-5aa60354d134b87842918d760ec8bc30-c23c5fbca96e8d641d148bac41017635|https://royalmechanical.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/hydro-power-plant.ppt,14,13
```

**Desired Result**:

```
Unique Urls: 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cut -d "|" -f 2 file | cut -d "," -f 1  | sort -u | wc -l
```

Output:

```
4
```

---

See: `man cut`, `man sort`

Comment: [root]# time cut -d "|" -f 2 myfile.log | cut -d "," -f 1  | sort -u | wc -l
2010
real    0m0.242s
user    0m0.258s
sys     0m0.019s


[root]# time echo Unique URLs: $(sed 's/^.*|\([^,]*\),.*$/\1/' myfile.log | uniq | wc -l)
Unique URLs: 2010

real    0m3.676s
user    0m4.136s
sys     0m0.070s

[root]# time awk '{sub(/^[^|]*\|/,"");gsub(/,[^,]*/,"");i+=a[$0]++?0:1}END{print i}' myfile.log
2010

real    0m0.943s
user    0m0.934s
sys     0m0.006s
[root]# time tr , '|' < myfile.log | sort -u -t '|' -k 2,2 | wc -l
2010
real    0m1.004s
user    0m0.996s
sys     0m0.039s

Comment: It is little bit mess but your answer is the most fastest one if you know how to make comment more human readable please help.

Answer (score 2):

An `awk` solution would be

```
awk '{sub(/^[^|]*\|/,"");gsub(/,[^,]*/,"");i+=a[$0]++?0:1}END{print i}' file
4
```

If you happen to use `GNU awk` then below would also give you the same result

```
awk '{i+=a[gensub(/.*(http[^,]*).*/,"\\1",1)]++?0:1}END{print i}' file
4
```

Or even short as pointed out in [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47465961/find-unique-urls-in-a-file/47466322?noredirect=1#comment81887345_47466322)  cracker comment by [**@cyrus**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776858/cyrus)

```
awk -F '[|,]' '{i+=!a[$2]++} END{print i}' file
4
```

which uses `awk` multiple field separator functionality with more idiomatic awk.

---

<sup>**Note:** See the [[  awk manual ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) for more info.</sup>

Comment: Or alternatively with your idea: `awk -F '[|,]' '{i+=!a[$2]++} END{print i}' file`

Comment: @Cyrus Appreciate that suggestion. Appended.

Answer (score 1):

1. Parse with `sed`, and since *file* appears to be already sorted,
   (with respect to URLs), just run `uniq`, and count it:

   ```
   echo Unique URLs: $(sed 's/^.*|\([^,]*\),.*$/\1/' file | uniq | wc -l)
   ```
2. Use *GNU* `grep` to extract URLs:

   ```
   echo Unique URLs: $(grep -o 'ht[^|,]*' file | uniq | wc -l)
   ```

Output (either method):

```
Unique URLs: 4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tr , '|' < myfile.log | sort -u -t '|' -k 2,2 | wc -l
```

- `tr , '|' < myfile.log` translates all commas into pipe characters
- `sort -u -t '|' -k 2,2` sorts unique (`-u`), pipe delimited (`-t '|'`), in the second field only (`-k 2,2`)
- `wc -l` counts the unique lines